# Getting derby database connection from Java (in eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jdbc, derby

I was following the following instructions:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html

in order to set-up a derby database server and everything works fine. I created the DB and could easily access it. however, these instructions use JSP to access my DB and I wand to change it so that I can access the DB through my custom Java classes but I cant create any connections to the DB. I simply tried:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
    ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/features", "root", "root");
```

Note: here my DB is names features

I get the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: 
No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/features
```

I tried loading the class for the driver:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

I dont know where to find and put **org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver**. How come in the instructions they only add a **context.xml** under META_INF and everything work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Did you:

> Copy the file derbyclient.jar from that folder to your TOMCAT_ROOT/lib
>   folder (if you're using Tomcat 5.x, install into
>   TOMCAT_ROOT/common/lib). This installs the Derby JDBC driver into
>   Tomcat for use in a DataSource.

You need the derbyclient.jar in the classpath.