# java - Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] not found

Tags: java, derby

Trying to connect to derby data base, and I get a below mentioned error:

```
Jan 17, 2014 2:05:36 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
[EL Info]: 2014-01-17 14:05:36.35--ServerSession(989603483)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2014-01-17 14:05:36.36--ServerSession(989603483)--Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] not found.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.mycompany.managingpersistanceobjects.App.main(App.java:20)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.configurationErrorClassNotFound(DatabaseException.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.loadDriverClass(DefaultConnector.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    ... 8 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.590s
Finished at: Fri Jan 17 14:05:36 CET 2014
Final Memory: 5M/121M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project ManagingPersistanceObjects: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here is a main class:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer("Anthony", "Balla", "tballa@mail.com");
        Address address = new Address("Rirherdon RD", "London", "8QE", "UK");
        customer.setAddress(address);

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("chapter06PU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

        et.begin();
        em.persist(customer);
        et.commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }
}
```

Here is Persistence Unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="chapter06PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter06PU;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The data base running:

```
Fri Jan 17 10:37:31 CET 2014 : Security manager installed using the Basic server
 security policy.
Fri Jan 17 10:37:31 CET 2014 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.1.1 - (145826
8) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

and I believe I have the dependency to the client in POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Can you advice?

Comment: Did you resolved it?i m facing the same problem,please give some insight

Comment: adding a library should resolve it. Check Meziane answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need just to use derbyclient instead of derby as artifactId:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type> 
</dependency>
```

......

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

Comment: Note: As of derby 10.15.1.3, we also need to include derbytools.jar. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216394/where-is-org-apache-derby-jdbc-clientdriver-for-version-10-15-1-3 for reference

Answer (score 3):

You need a derby driver installer in the application server for this to work.  It is not enough to include it in your application itself.

The simplest way to do so for the Java distributions at the time the question was asked, as I believe Derby is included in the JDK, is to tell JBoss to use the JDK instead of the default JRE.

Comment: He can too the load a class of Derby package, for example: Class.forName(org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.class) : if this instruction does'nt exception , then the package is correctly present in the general classpat.

Answer (score 1):

Says the JDBC driver is not found. Have you included it in your library?

Answer (score 0):

You must copy derbyclient.jar in your Tomcat server's lib folder.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8263229/1726308) answer.